# Navigation Drawer for every activity throws a null pointer Exception in onCreate

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've been following a tutorial to get the Navigation Drawer to every activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     *  Frame layout: Which is going to be used as parent layout for child activity layout.
     *  This layout is protected so that child activity can access this
     *  */
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;

    /**
     * ListView to add navigation drawer item in it.
     * We have made it protected to access it in child class. We will just use it in child class to make item selected according to activity opened.
     */

    protected ListView mDrawerList;

    /**
     * List item array for navigation drawer items.
     * */
    protected String[] listArray = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };

    /**
     * Static variable for selected item position. Which can be used in child activity to know which item is selected from the list.
     * */
    protected static int position;

    /**
     *  This flag is used just to check that launcher activity is called first time
     *  so that we can open appropriate Activity on launch and make list item position selected accordingly.
     * */
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;

    /**
     *  Base layout node of this Activity.
     * */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    /**
     * Drawer listner class for drawer open, close etc.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, listArray));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
            }
        });

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.string.drawer_open,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        /**
         * As we are calling BaseActivity from manifest file and this base activity is intended just to add navigation drawer in our app.
         * We have to open some activity with layout on launch. So we are checking if this BaseActivity is called first time then we are opening our first activity.
         * */
        if(isLaunch){
            /**
             *Setting this flag false so that next time it will not open our first activity.
             *We have to use this flag because we are using this BaseActivity as parent activity to our other activity.
             *In this case this base activity will always be call when any child activity will launch.
             */
            isLaunch = false;
            openActivity(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param position
     *
     * Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
     */
    protected void openActivity(int position) {

        /**
         * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
         * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
         * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
         * So that we are setting this in child activity.
         */
//      mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//      setTitle(listArray[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item1Activity.class));
                break;
            case 1:
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item2Activity.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item3Activity.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item4Activity.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item5Activity.class));
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }
}
```

And I get a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.udazz.udazz.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:91)
    at net.udazz.udazz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
```

I've tried replacing `onCreate` with `onCreateDrawer` but it didn't help either

Here it's the code for the custom theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity: I think the problem is in setContentView. I need the WebView in this Activity. Here it goes the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Hide the semy cirle at th bottom of the action bar when the user slides to the top
        mWebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                view.stopLoading();  // may not be needed
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorPage.HTML");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //sendRegistrationIdToBackend();
                //getCookies();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains("pics")) {
                    Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyPostsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                } else if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().length() == 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {                // Otherwise, give the default behavior (open in browser)
                    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://url/");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
       // mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is at like 36 & 91?

Comment: 91 is getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 36 is super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Which theme are you using for BaseActivity?

Comment: extend ActionBarActivity instead of Activity

Comment: I have a custom theme for the entire application

Comment: Please post your custom theme.

Comment: I changed Activity for AppCompatActivity and the app runs but I cannot see the menu icon (hamburger icon)

Comment: I posted the custom theme

Comment: When i slide the menu is empty....

Comment: May be Because of this line menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen); in your onPrepareOptionsMenu method.

Comment: It's not that @Dhaval Patel

Comment: I think it is the setContentView I'm using in the MainActivity

Comment: @ Mariano Pelizzari Please Post code of MainActivity.

Comment: Already done @Dhaval Patel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78466/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-mariano-pelizzari).